# Dynamically Detecting Alt Text of Image with Dynamic Class List

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a cover flow section on my page which the movements of the cover images are controlled by the left/right buttons linked with Javascript. Whenever a cover image is moved to the center, an `active` class is added to the class list of that image and removed from the previous images. I also have a simple jquery that I want to detect the `alt` text of that current active cover image. I implemented an onClick event listener on the left/right buttons. Whenever the button is clicked, the jquery is triggered. The problem is that, when I click on the button, it does detect the `alt` text of the current centered image with `active` class, it only detects the `alt` text of the center image when the page first loaded.

The HTML is like follow:

```html
<div class="coverflow">
    <div class="cover active"><img src="..." alt="A"></div>
    <div class="cover"><img src="..." alt="B"></div>
    ...
    <div class="cover"><img src="..." alt="Y"></div>
    <div class="cover"><img src="..." alt="Z"></div>
</div>
<button class="left" onclick="getAlt();">Left</button>
<button class="right" onclick="getAlt();">Right</button>
```

The JQuery is like follow:

```
<script>
function getAlt() {
    var alt = $('.cover,.active').find('img').attr('alt');
    alert($alt);
}
</script>
```

In my above case, no matter which image is centered on the screen, the alert box always shows "A" instead of other alt text. My excepted result should be having the alert box shows the `alt` text of the center active image dynamically upon images rotation. Does anyone know where went wrong when my sample above?

Answer (score 0):

You used wrong selector. `$('.cover,.active')` will return all element that have class `cover` or `active`. You should use `$('.cover.active')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should be able to get the value of current `alt` with:

```
$('.active img').attr('alt');
```

The following demo shows how a possible slider can utilize the `alt` value as the caption of the current `<img>`.

BTW never use on-event attributes (ex. `<div onclick=functionName()...>`)
if you load jQuery because a jQuery event method (ex. `$('div').click(functionName)` or `$('div').on('click', functionName)`) is versatile, and easy to maintain -- on-event attributes aren't.

```js
$('.active').fadeIn();
$('.active .text').text($('.active img').attr('alt'));

$('.go').on('click', cover);

function cover(e) {
  var idx = $('.active').index();
  var prev = idx;
  var last = $('.cover').length - 1;
  var dir = $(this).hasClass('right') ? idx + 1 : idx - 1;
  if (dir < 0) {
    dir = last;
  }
  if (dir > last) {
    dir = 0;
  }
  $('.cover').each(function(i) {
    if (dir === i) {
      $(this).fadeIn().addClass('active');
    } else if (i === prev) {
      $(this).fadeOut().removeClass('active');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
  });
  var alt = $('.active img').attr('alt');
  console.log(alt);
  $('.active .text').text(alt);
}
```

```css
.coverflow {
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cover {
  display: none;
}

button {
  font-size: 3rem;
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translateY(125px)
}

button:focus {
  outline: none
}

.left {
  float: left
}

.right {
  float: right
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3rem
}


/* For demo purposes */

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 25px !important;
  max-width: 30%;
  margin-left: 70%
}
```

```html
<button class="go left">&#9664;</button>
<button class="go right">&#9654;</button>
<section class="coverflow">
  <figure class="cover active"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/06/26/11/35/letter-3499237_960_720.png" alt="A" width='320' height='180'>
    <figcaption class='text'></figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure class="cover"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/01/05/21/27/letter-3915960_960_720.png" alt="B" width='320' height='180'>
    <figcaption class='text'></figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure class="cover"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/03/08/27/alphabet-2034721_960_720.png" alt="Y" width='320' height='180'>
    <figcaption class='text'></figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure class="cover"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/26/14/30/alphabet-2010699_960_720.png" alt="Z" width='320' height='180'>
    <figcaption class='text'></figcaption>
  </figure>
</section>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your example code, my issue has been resolved.